# How to match exponent that might be 1?

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to apply the following rule

```
m^p_ :> (m^p - Log[n]^p)
```

to `m^x` where `x` may be one.

This works if `x` is not one,

```
m^2 /. m^p_ :> (m^p - Log[n]^p)
(* m^2 - Log[n]^2 *)
```

but fails if `x==1`

```
m /. m^p_ :> (m^p - Log[n]^p)
(* m *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Default.html) pattern `_.`

> - _. represents an optional argument to a function, with a default value 
>     specified by `Default`.
>
>   - Values defined for `Default[f]` are stored in `DefaultValues[f]`.

```
DefaultValues[Power]
```

> {HoldPattern[Default[Power, 2]] :> 1}

If the second argument in `Power[x,p]` is omitted, the default value of 1 is used:

```
Power[y]
```

> y

```
m /. m^p_. :> (m^p - Log[n]^p)
```

> m - Log[n]

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why here the Default value of p is 1?

Comment: @ablmf, default value of the second argument of `Power` is `1` (`FullForm` of `x^p`  is `Power[x, p]`)

Comment: ... similarly for `Times`, `m /. (_.) m :> foo[m]` gives `foo[m]` and for `Plus`, `m /. m + _. :> bar[m]` gives `bar[m]`.